# React-Router-Redux dispatched LOCATION_CHANGE twice, remove search value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using the next (5.0.0-alpha.6) version react-router-redux which is compatible with react-router 4.x.
I try to set parameter on url while redirect to next page.

Every time it moves to the next page. I realize that it call @LOCATION_CHANGE 2 time, [in the second time it removes search value](https://imgur.com/gzb1oZR). It works fine if I handle it from button event

```
import { requireAuth } from '../components/AuthenticatedComponent'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()  

return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={requireAuth(About)} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  )
```

**AuthenticatedComponent.js**

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

export function requireAuth(Component) {

class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.checkAuth(this.props.isAuthenticated);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.checkAuth(nextProps.isAuthenticated);
    }

    checkAuth(isAuthenticated) {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            let redirectAfterLogin = this.props.location.pathname;
            this.props.dispatch(push({pathname: "/login", search:`?redirect=${redirectAfterLogin}`}))
        }
    }
 //....
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) is no longer maintained. For your Redux <-> Router syncing needs with React Router 4+. Let's use [connected-react-route](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router)r library instead will resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the pathname in nextProps.

```
class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

//...

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.checkAuth(nextProps.isAuthenticated); // <--- call checkAuth
}

checkAuth(isAuthenticated) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) { // <-- isAuthenticated is in nextProps

        // this.props.location.pathame is not in nextProps
        let redirectAfterLogin = this.props.location.pathname;
        this.props.dispatch(push({pathname: "/login", search:`?redirect=${redirectAfterLogin}`}))
    }
 }

//...
```

---

```
class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.checkAuth(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.checkAuth(nextProps); // <--- call checkAuth
}

checkAuth({isAuthenticated, location, dispatch}) {
    if (!isAuthenticated) { 
        let redirectAfterLogin = location.pathname;
        dispatch(push({pathname: "/login", search:`?redirect=${redirectAfterLogin}`}))
    }
 }

//...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it seems like not work for me
https://gyazo.com/77ca970422d4e29d6dcc418435417977

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this question with a similar problem, I was using the `connected-react-router` library and `push` was causing a double `LOCATION_CHANGE` event to fire off. The first event would have the correct search params while the second one would clear it. My issue was I was rendering a button as a `Link` from `react-router-dom` as so:

```
<Button
  as={Link}
  basic
  className={styles.basicTealButton}
  onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
>
...
```

Once I got rid of the `as={Link}` part, everything worked fine.